# Remote Desktop freezing the remote computer

Tags: remote-desktop, remote

My work computer will freeze when I Remote Desktop to it from any other computer either at work or from home.  I have to perform a hard reset which I don't like to do in order to get it running again.  There are over 20 computers are work and there are only 2 that are having this problem.

Dell PC, Quad Core, running XP SP 3.  Firewall service is NOT running.

This is also happening with another computer here on our network. The user is using VNC to work from home.

Has anyone had this problem before? If so what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd check is to make sure that the machines have up-to-date video drivers.

Comment: That seems to have resolved the issue when connecting from another computer in the building.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows 7 (perhaps only 64bit), disabling the remote audio under the "local resources" tab have helped many. You might want to try and updating the audio drivers on both computers first.